How to make tabBar exactly like this?
I tried many times but somethings is always missing. I want exactly the same, the design,border.


You can use CupertinoSegmentedControl:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSegmentedControl-class.html
here are some examples and the way you can customize it:
https://medium.com/@sebbenkra/a-material-styled-segmented-control-1e92310c3a67
